# C++ Interrupts?

Tags: c++, interrupt

I was wondering if C++ had any way of doing interrupts. I want one program to store information in a text file, while the other one prints a statement depending on what is in the text file. Since I want it to be as accurate as possible, I need the print program to be interrupted when the update program updates the file.

Comment: Interrupts are more an OS thing, which OS are you using?

Comment: File are not a very good way of doing inter-process communication.  Any chance you could use a pipe or a socket instead?

Answer (score 1):

C++ itself doesn't give this capability, it knows nothing of other programs that may or may not be running.

What you need to look into is IPC (inter-process communications), something your operating system will probably provide.

Things like signals, shared memory, semaphores, message queues and so on.

Since you seem to be using the file itself as the method of delivering content to the other process, signals are probably the way to go.  You would simply raise a signal from process A to process B and a signal handler would run in the latter.

Of course this all depends on *which* operating system you're targeting.

Comment: I plan on using Windows, but if Linux is better, I can use that, too. But before that, The overall project of mines includes program A and program B as mentioned above, and hardware that is connected to program B. Instead of B printing, it sends commands to the hardware to light up certain buttons. Is a Linux server capable of interacting with hardware on my side?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you can use [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Here's some old code I have. This is run in it's own thread:

```
DWORD CDiskWatcher::Run(void *vpParameter)
{
    CFileNotifyInterface *pIface = (CFileNotifyInterface *)vpParameter;

    HANDLE handles[2];
    handles[0] = m_hQuitEvent;
    handles[1] = ::FindFirstChangeNotification(m_szPath, FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE|FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
    DWORD dwObject;
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != handles[1]) {
        do {
            // Wait for the notification
            dwObject = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
            if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 == dwObject) {
                // Continue waiting...
                ::FindNextChangeNotification(handles[1]);
                pIface->FireFileSystemChange(m_szPath);
            }
        } while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != dwObject);
        // Close handle
        ::FindCloseChangeNotification(handles[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note m_hQuitEvent is created with CreateEvent() and CFileNotifyInterface is for callbacks:

```
class CFileNotifyInterface
{
public:
    virtual void FireFileSystemChange(const char *szPath) = 0;
};
```